# SASS Selecting all elements expect first child

Tags: sass, css-selectors

Trying to achieve the following in SASS but I have been unsuccessful with the $:not(:first-child):before selector

Link | Link | Link

HTML Code
    `<ul class="multistore">
    <li class="tab">
       <a class="tab-link">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tab">
       <a class="tab-link">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tab">
       <a class="tab-link">Link</a>
    </li>
</ul>`

SASS

```
.tab-link {
    &:not(:first-child):before {
          content: "|";
    }      
}
```

Issue is my result is

| Link | Link | Link

But Im thinking it may be due to the A tag inside the li and every A is the first child of li.

PS Content has to be added to the A element not li due to layout design.

Comment: `:before` should be `::before`, according to the latest [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#pseudo-elements)

Comment: **Every** `tab-link` you've shown matches `:first-child`.

Comment: @connexo Yes I just realized thats the issue, Just trying to think what right selector can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is what you want:

```css
.multistore { list-style-type: none; }
.multistore li { display: inline-block; }

.tab:not(:first-child) .tab-link::before {
  content: "| ";
}
```

```html
<ul class="multistore">
  <li class="tab">
    <a class="tab-link">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="tab">
    <a class="tab-link">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="tab">
    <a class="tab-link">Link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This works but it has an issue: The `|` becomes part of the clickable link, and to the user it will be unclear to which link this part belongs. That is why I would highly recommend putting the `|` on the `li` instead.

P.S.: In SCSS:

```
.tab {
  &:not(:first-child) {
    .tab-link {
      &::before {
       content: "| ";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly. I wasn't fussed with the | becoming clickable, The A is 100% width and height of the li. So unnoticeable.